# List value not persistent out of method

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

So, I'll try to make this simple. I use this call to update my list **spisak** with relevant data:

```
parent.queryDatabase(spisak, params);
```

And the method is as follows:

```
public void queryDatabase(List<School> spisak, String[] args) {
    databaseHelper.open();
    Cursor c;
    c = databaseHelper.getAllSchools();
    if(!c.moveToFirst()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ova pretraga nije vratila nijednu školu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        spisak = cursorToSchool(c);
    }
    databaseHelper.close();
}
public List<School> cursorToSchool(Cursor c) {
    //Converts the Cursor object to temporary School object
    List<School> listing = new ArrayList<School>();
    School s = new School();
    do {
        s.setId(c.getInt(0));
        s.setName(c.getString(1));
        s.setAddress(c.getString(2));
        s.setEntryExam(String.valueOf(c.getInt(3)));
        s.setNoS(c.getInt(4));
        s.setTelephone(c.getString(5));
        s.setWebsite(c.getString(6));
        listing.add(s);
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());
    return listing;
}
```

Within the called methods the duplicated variable **spisak** contains the data it should have (I checked during debugging), but out of that scope (back in the FragmentActivity that called the method) the real **spisak** is empty i.e. the changes made in the called method aren't persistent. So how should I reference the **spisak** variable when I'm calling it within FragmentActivity so that it can retain values assigned to it in that method.
For example, in Pascal:

Calling methodname(x:integer) won't persist data

Calling methodname(var x:integer) will persist data...

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the way parameters are passed to a method. In `queryDatabase()` you have a reference to `spisak`, which is a reference from an object outide this method, then you change the reference to `spisak`. Simply put, you can change (like calling `add()` or `remove()`) `spisak` inside `queryDatabase()`, but you can't change its reference.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you instantiate a new object, it's stored in a memory position.

Consider that, outside you `queryDatabase()` method, the variable you are passing as `spisak` is stored in memory position 1000.

When `queryDatabase()` receives the `spisak`, its basically receiving a pointer to the memory position 1000.

Your `cursorToSchool()` method always create a new `List<School>` variable and returns it. So, every time you call `cursorToSchool()`, you are creating a new object and addressing it to a new memory position.

So when you call `spisak = cursorToSchool(c);` on `queryDatabase()`, you are creating a new object (let's say it's in memory position 2000) and storing it in the variable `spisak`. Now `spisak` points to memory position 2000.

The problem is that who called the `queryDatabase()` has a variable pointin to memory position 1000 and all you did was change the memory position 2000. In other words, you are changing everything you want inside `queryDatabase()`, but to the one who called it, you are doing nothing.

A possible solution to your problem is to return a `List<School>` instead of making it void, then you return your `spisak` variable.